# Linq groupby query with projection

Tags: linq, grouping

I'm trying to group orders by customer id then project the orders returned (by customer) into a List.  Trying to figure out how I would do this?

```
 List<OrderGroup> set = OrderRepository.GetAllOrders
     .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId).Select(result => new OrderGroup
         {
             Orders = ???? //should be all orders from one customer.
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Linq-to-Sql, Entity Framework, other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `result` is an [`IGrouping<TKey, T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx), which is itself an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can do:

```
List<OrderGroup> set = OrderRepository.GetAllOrders
                      .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId)
                      .Select(result => new OrderGroup
                      {
                          Orders = result.ToList()
                      }).ToList();
```

(Note that this assumes `Orders` is assignable from a `List<Order>`.)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like below. I like to select columns that are needed instead of getting all.

```
var customerData = (from cd in OrderRepository.GetAllOrders
                     group cd by new { cd.CustomerId, cd.date } into grp
                    select new
                       {
                           customer_name = grp.FirstOrDefault().custname,
                           total_orders = grp.Count(),  
                           amount = grp.Sum(x => x.total_amt_paid)

                       }).ToList();                    


foreach (var data in customerData)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reed's right, though I believe you could also use the result selector to achieve this, like so:

```
List<OrderGroup> set = OrderRepository.GetAllOrders
                         .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId, // key selector
                           x => x, // element selector
                           result => new OrderGroup
                           {
                              Orders = result.ToList()
                           }) // result selector
                         .ToList();
```

(I don't have a compiler in front of me to verify.)